# Grub not starting when dual booting with windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I have been attempting to install Ubuntu to dual boot alongside Windows 10 Home, but no matter what I have tried I cannot get Grub to boot. So far I have tried changing the boot manager path entry to /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi using this command in Windows: `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`

This has yielded no results, and my computer still boots through the default windows entry. If I go into by UEFI Firmware settings and choose "Boot from an EFI File" the grubx64.efi file is not visible, and when I click on the folder Ubuntu it displays a message along the lines of "No valid files are contained in this folder".

I have also tried enabling the graphical boot loader via EasyBCD and the bcdedit command, but every time I reboot my computer it again boots directly to Windows without showing this bootloader.

I have disabled secure boot, fast startup, and disabled bit locking and completely unencrypted my drive. I have looked online and found articles listing that you must list EFI files as trusted in the firmware settings, but my UEFI firmware settings show no such option.

This laptop came with Windows pre-installed. In case anyone is wondering, it is a HP 15t-ep000 model with Intel Optane. Is it just impossible to dual boot because of firmware restrictions?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that while installing Ubuntu in a separate partition, I chose both my drive and the EFI file system partition as the location to install the boot loader.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu? Waht version? Did you use an *iso image on a flash drive?

Comment: @darth_epoxy I installed Ubuntu Budgie 20.04.2 LTS via an ISO imaged flash drive.

Comment: So can you boot to the flash drive and run a live version of Ubuntu? If so open gparted and show us your driver setup (take a screenshot).